# why setting backgroundImage on uiviews slowed down my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an iOS app which includes 2 UITableViewController,
Pressing on the **first** tableview cell pushes the **second** tableview, the ***transition*** was pretty fast (going back/forth between the two tableviews) until i used this code on each tableviews viewWillAppear method:

```
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"un.jpeg"] applyBlurWithRadius:50
                                                            tintColor:nil
                                                saturationDeltaFactor:1 
                                                            maskImage:nil];
imageV.image = image;
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageV;
```

Now the transition takes about 2-3 seconds to be done how can i improve transition speed ?

Edit 1: using UIImage+ImageEffects.h from Apple to blur the image

Edit 2 (solution):

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"un.jpeg"] applyBlurWithRadius:50
                                                                tintColor:nil
                                                    saturationDeltaFactor:1
                                                                maskImage:nil];
    imageV.image = image;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageV;
});
```

Comment: What is `applyBlurWithRadius`...? If it's a CIFilter, yeah, they are slow. Run that code in the background, or blur in a faster way.

Comment: I'm using UIImage+ImageEffects.h from Apple

Comment: Yeah, I remember that. It's faster than a CIFilter but could still be slowing you down. I would suggest, as I said, applying the blur on a background thread, so it doesn't slow your interface down.

Comment: thanks man background thread (dispatch_once) was the solution cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest applying the blur on a background thread, so it doesn't slow your interface down. And you might want to look into GPUImage for maximum speed.

Alternatively, in iOS 8, just use the UIBlurEffect that is built in. But of course that is a much less flexible blur.

Comment: And make sure your image is only as large as needs to be! (If you're blurring maybe a 1x resolution works for all devices.)

Answer (score 1):

What slows your application the most is certainly not the image, but rather the blur that you apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Is not setting the image per se, is applying the blur on it.
The bigger is the image the longer it takes. I don't know which kind of functionalities you are using to make the image blurred, but check if you can use the accelerate framework or Core Image on GPU to perform the operation faster.